# paperjs PointText click and drag the handles to scale and resize

Tags: paperjs

In paperjs I can not find a way to re size the text item pointText. I would like my users to be able to click to select the text item, then when the handles appear be able to drag to re size the text (keeping the aspect ratio). No where in the docs is it clear or doable. I have a feeling that I'm missing something or its not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a `hitTest` only on the bounds of `PointText` items.

```
var text = new PointText({
    point: [50, 50],
    content: 'The contents of the point text',
    fillColor: 'black',
    fontSize: 25,
    selected: true
});

function onMouseDown(event){
    text.res = project.hitTest(event.point, {
            type: 'PointText',
            bounds:true
        }
    );
    console.log(text.res.name);
}
```

Then parse the result to make sure it's a corner and perform a scale centered on the opposite corner on the next `onMouseUp`.

Comment: I'm having trouble, the results I get is the bound names: Can you show me how I would do this with the mouseUp function?

Comment: In the case above `text.res` should be the full `hitResult` object if you hit a bounds control. If not, it will return null. All you need is the name of which corner it was to switch between possibilities. Then you can scale the object by the `event.delta` relative to the text size.

Comment: This is how to detect a text item on click, this has nothing to do with text scaling.